# How can I set delimiters between two numbers without setting the delimiter between two words on the same line in Python?

Tags: python, delimiter

I have the following code:

```
text = 'hello world 2,000 3,000'
text = text.replace(' ', '|')
print text
```

The output is:

```
hello|world|2,000|3,000
```

I want to delimit using '|' but I want the output to be in three columns.  I don't want the words to be delimited from eachother, just the words from the numbers:

```
hello world|2,000|3,000
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expression replacement:

```
import re

text = 'hello world 2,000 3,000'
print re.sub(r'\s(\d)', '|\\1', text)
```

This only inserts a pipe mark for things preceded by a space and a digit.

Answer (score 2):

You have three fields separated by spaces and the first field may also contain spaces. You can use `rsplit` with the maxsplit argument to split the string into three parts from the right.

```
text = 'hello world 2,000 3,000'

# Split at the two rightmost spaces, so that
# the leftmost of the three fields can contain spaces
parts = text.rsplit(' ', 2) # ['hello world', '2,000', '3,000']

result = '|'.join(parts) # 'hello world|2,000|3,000'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a regex you do this:
This is assuming that you have many lines of input and putting them all in a list of lists.
It returns a list of lists where each elements is the properly parsed string.

This only assumes that your fields are separated by a space and that you would like to not have a pipe between the first two fields.

```
# one line of input
text = 'hellow world 1,000 2,000'
testlist = text.split(' ')

# all your input
list_of_all_text = [testlist] + [testlist] + [testlist]

first_feilds = map(lambda x: x[0]+' '+x[1],list_of_all_text)
last_feilds = map(lambda x: x[2:],list_of_all_text)
all_feilds = map(lambda x,y: [x]+y,first_feilds,last_feilds)
parsed_feilds = map(lambda x: '|'.join(x),all_feilds)
print parsed_feilds
```

or the less readable and more compact:

```
text = 'hellow world 1,000 2,000'
testlist = text.split(' ')
list_of_all_text = [testlist] + [testlist] + [testlist]
map(lambda x: '|'.join(x),map(lambda x,y: [x]+y,map(lambda x: x[0]+' '+x[1],list_of_all_text),map(lambda x: x[2:],list_of_all_text)))
```